# Configuring wildcard topic selectors in ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, nms

Based on the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NMS/ActiveMQ+Wildcards) wildcards support does exist, but I can't seem to find any other info on whether it's just supposed to work or if it's configured on the server or whether the producers or consumers need to configure it.

I'm assuming as a publisher I would just send messages to a topic named `/patient/2/goal/` and when a consumer subscribed to a topic called `/patient/*/goal/` it would still receive the message, however nothing shows up. What am I missing?

Please note that if I publish a message to `/patient/*/goal/` and subscribe to `/patient/*/goal/` then I receive the message. However, that only confirms my message bus is working, not that wildcard support is working.

Producer test:

```
var connectUri = new Uri("...");
var factory = new NMSConnectionFactory(connectUri);
var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
session = connection.CreateSession();
var destination = session.GetTopic("/patient/1/goal/");
producer = session.CreateProducer(destination);
...
```

Consumer:

```
var topic = _session.GetTopic("/patient/*/goal/");
var consumer = _session.CreateConsumer(topic);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `/` as the the path separator needs to be configured through a plugin. Switching to `.` made it work as expected.